# Imagemagick: animated gif background flatten

Tags: transparency, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I'm wondering how to remove and replace transparency in an animated GIF with ImageMagick.

My goal is to take several *pages* with different aspect ratios and make an animated GIF that cycles through them.

[document1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgz9d.png)

I am using 

`convert -delay 50 -resize 212 -dispose Previous -page 212x275 -crop 212x275+0+0 +repage document1.png document2.png documents.gif 2>&1`

to create the GIF.

This sizes my documents correctly, but leaves the empty space from the short images transparent, but I would like that to be white. How can I change the transparency to white?

[doc.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTsIy.gif)

I have tried

`convert doc.gif -background black -alpha off doc2.gif
convert doc.gif -background black -flatten doc2.gif`

-alpha doesn't seem to do anything, and -flatten removes the animation